# How do I use the sword and shield I found?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm just starting Dark Souls as a Warrior, and have encountered the first giant monster, archer, and sword-wielding opponents, and have found a shield and a sword, but I can't seem to equip either of them, and don't know why.

I can get to them in inventory, but when I select them, their "use" option has a line through it, and pressing that button does nothing.

I checked the [wiki](http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Shields) and it seems I should have plenty of Strength for the shield (I start with Strength 13)... is there some other requirement before I can equip them, or am I just being stumped by the UI?

Comment: Are you playing with KbM or controller?

Comment: I tried KbM but the mouse pointer wanders on the desktop during play and can cause clicks to interrupt the game. Then I tried my flight stick and bought xpadder and configured it with that, but the main trigger invokes the settings menu for some reason, and buttons I mapped as an attack key are instead doing a useless chest-pounding gesture, and xpadder also doesn't notice I calibrated my joystick, so it won't let me walk backwards. I may go back to KbM using a mouse with more buttons and avoid using LMB.

Comment: You should try out Cursor Lock for the wandering mouse problem. Otherwise I'd recommend buying a wired controller for the optimal Souls experience.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Cursor Lock. I almost did buy a controller, but I really don't like modern game console controllers with the two thumb sticks.

Comment: More power to you then! I usually prefer KbM but I just couldn't get Dark Souls until I  used a controller.

Comment: Ya, I think part of the problem with KbM is something I read where the character has a limited turn speed which a mouse can exceed, causing out-of-sync, which makes you move a weird direction when you turn with mouse and then move. I think my joystick would actually work well if the buttons weren't also being interpreted by the game as xbox buttons as well as keystrokes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you might be on your Inventory screen rather than the Equipment screen, which is where you need to go to equip gear and set your quick-access items. Does the screen you're looking at look something like this?

[image: Dark Souls inventory screen screenshot]

If so, you want to use RB/R1 (or your controls' equivalent) to switch to the Equipment screen, which should look like this:

[image: Dark Souls equipment screen screenshot]

From this screen, you can select the slot that you want to equip something to. From top to bottom, left to right, those are: weapon (2), shield or off-hand item (2), armor (4), quick-access items (5), arrows (2), crossbow bolts (2), and rings (2).

If you have multiple weapons or off-hand items equipped, you can switch between them using Left and Right on the D-pad (or your controls' equivalent) during gameplay.

Comment: Yep, I was on the Inventory screen. I guess I must have stopped there and not gone to the Equipment screen after finding the sword and shield. Thanks!